# How to insert PHP code into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I want to insert some PHP code into a MySQL table and retrieve from it in the future, just like a normal string. But when I put the PHP code into an INSERT query, a MySQL error happens. I think MySQL prevents to execute the query because of the SQL injection security problems.

```php
<?php
    $a="<?php $query='insert into ...';
    mysql_query($query);
    ....
    ?>";
    $query="insert into test (`id`,`code`) value (1,$a)";
    mysql_query($query);
?>
```

Comment: Error is (at least) in quotes' absence

Comment: yes, the code that i try to insert is a part of my project.
really i want to have some pages for my actual project documentation.

Comment: i want to save a block of code like methods or classes , and then retrieve it , and show with some comments for other programers.

Comment: @ehsan the answers below dont resolve your issue?

Comment: As noted, there are trivial syntax errors in the code you posted, starting from an orphaned PHP tag and continuing with the ellipsis in the query. Please provide a working code snippet (this one is not) and the actual query; you can obfuscate confidential database names.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.